# Read two csv files and compare every line. If the lines match print both lines, if it isn't similar print invalid

Tags: python

```
import csv

f1 = open("file1.csv")

f2 = open("file2.csv")

csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)

csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2)

for row1 in csv_f1: 
    for row2 in csv_f2:
        if row1 == row2:
            print row1[0], row2[0]
        else:
            print row1[0], "Invalid"
```

this program isn't printing out row1, row2. It's just printing first line of file1 and invalid on the same line several times.

Comment: If file1 contains N lines and file2 contains M lines, your code is going to be making N*M comparisons (line 1 in file1 will be compared against each line in file2, then line 2 in file1 will be compared against each line in file2, etc.).  Is that your intent?

Comment: yes, that is right and if they are similar just print row1 and row2. else, always print row1, but invalid if it doesn't match with row1. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to compare the corresponding rows, not each row with each row, which is what your code does right now.

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import csv
import itertools
import sys

# Select the right function based on whether we are in Python 2 or 3.
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    zip_longest = itertools.izip_longest
else:
    zip_longest = itertools.zip_longest

f1 = open("file1.csv")
f2 = open("file2.csv")

csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2)

for row1, row2 in zip_longest(csv_f1, csv_f2):
    if row1 == row2:
        print(row1[0], row2[0])
    else:
        print(row1[0], "Invalid")
```

Comment: thanks for your time and we did make some progress. But, now its printing row1 and invalid for all the lines. thank you again

Comment: It works for the toy CSV files I created. Add a couple of lines from each of your files to the question.

Comment: f1 has 300 lines and f2 has 120 lines. The exercise wants me to print row1 and row2 if they match or row1 and invalid if they don't.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you need to check if *any* row from F2 matches *any* from F1? You can post both files on http://pastebin.com/.

Comment: never mind i got them working thanks for your help i really appreciate it.

Comment: i have this error :
module 'itertools' has no attribute 'izip'

Comment: getting error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zip_longest'"

Answer (score 3):

1. Read two CSV files and create dictionary which has key as line number and value as row
2. Iterator on file1 i.e. `root1` and compare with file2 i.e. `root2` with the same key.
3. Handle exception when file1 has more entries then file2.

Code:

```
import csv
with open("/home/infogrid/Desktop/file1.csv", "rb") as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1,)
    root1 = {}
    for i in root:
        root1[root.line_num] = i
    
with open("/home/infogrid/Desktop/file2.csv", "rb") as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1,)
    root2 = {}
    for i in root:
        root2[root.line_num] = i

for i in root1:
    try:
        if root1[i]==root2[i]:
            print root1[i], root1[i]
        else:
            print root1[i], "Invalid"
    except:
        print root1[i], "Invalid"
```

Output:

```
['test1', 'test3', 'test4'] ['test1', 'test3', 'test4']
['test1', 'test5', 'test4'] Invalid
['test1', 'test3', 'test4'] ['test1', 'test3', 'test4']
['test1', 'test3', 'test4'] Invalid
```